# Applying Style to Anchor Element Causes Unexpected Expansion of Content

Tags: html, css

This is the page before the style was added:
[image: Initial Style Before Capture]

And this is afterwards:
[image: After Capture]

I am not sure what is causing the error. The only thing I know for sure is that when I apply a background color, the entire thing goes wack. The idea was to get a download button with a nice background against the white so that it stands out to the user. However, it seems that the element has inherited the height value from it's parent. Is there any clean and concise fix to this problem?

```css
:root {
    --default-width: 600px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}


header {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    height: 600px;
}

header h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 540px;
}

header p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 620px;
}

header a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 720px;
}

main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: var(--default-width);
}

.header-nav {
    text-align: right
}

.header-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.header-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out 0s, color 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.header-nav li:hover {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    color: white;
}

.important-button {
    color: blue;
    background-color: whitesmoke;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <title>Scriptura</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="header-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <header>
      <h1>Welcome To <em>Scriptura</em></h1>
      <p>The premier note-taking software on the web!</p>
      <a class="important-button" href="#">Download Now!</a>
    </header>

    <main>
      <section>
        <h2>What Is <em>Scriptura</em></h2>
        <p>
          <em>Scriptura</em> begins with the bare-bones features of text-editing when you download it initially; however, as your needs expand, you can add more and more to it, like:
        </p>
        <ol>
          <li>Custom Note Templates</li>
          <li>Customizable Themes</li>
          <li>Data Displays (Tables, Cells, Grouping Columns etc.)</li>
          <li>And more on the way!</li>
        </ol>
      </section>
    </main>


    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It may have something to do with how the element is positioned, but please note that I was using an absolute centering trick to get the desired affect you see in the initial shot. So if it is possible, please keep the content in the header vertically and horizontally centered.

Answer (score 1):

For anchor tag you gave position absolute, It mean that it looks for its parent with position relative element and takes the with and height of the parent element with position relative.

So if you make the below changes it looks like the requirement

```
header a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 10px 16px;
}
```

Comment: I unaccepted the answer because I am hoping to draw a little bit more attention to this topic. I also asked for something a little bit more clean and concise.